# MySql 5.5 in ubuntu repository

Tags: mysql-5.5, ubuntu

Sorry for duplicate question.

I am looking for the best way to install mysql 5.5 on ubuntu.

So far, there are few options:

- Installing from tar.gz
- Installing from PPA.
- Alien on RPM.

All of them don't seem to be optimal to me. Installing from tar.gz takes long time and might have room for mistake. Installing from PPA is dangerous, I don't want to install something on production server which is non-official or might have differecens with official version. Running alien on RPM not a good way to install.

How did you install Mysql 5.5 on ubuntu server?

Version: Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Comment: For a start, what version of Ubuntu?

Comment: @Phil, sorry of couse, Ubuntu 10.04.3 LTS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are .deb packages available. Using the ones from http://people.debian.org/~nobse/mysql-5.5/:

```
sudo su -
wget http://people.debian.org/~nobse/mysql-5.5/mysql-common_5.5.13-2_all.deb
wget http://people.debian.org/~nobse/mysql-5.5/mysql-server_5.5_5.5.13-2_amd64.deb

dpkg -i mysql-common_5.5.13-2_all.deb
dpkg -i mysql-server_5.5_5.5.13-2_amd64.deb
```

The first dpkg execution may ask for you to install dependencies. If you're installing on a 32-bit system, alter the URLs accordingly.

Latest .debs are available on http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/#downloads - Select "Debian Linux".

Comment: 5.5.13 it is old version

Comment: Try the .debs from the MySQL site

Comment: I tried one, it takes 20 sec to run installation and at the end it exists without error messages, *Setting up mysql (5.5.23) ...*

Comment: What does `dpkg-query --status mysql-server-5.5` say (or common, if that's the one you tried installing)?

Comment: *dpkg-query --status mysql-5.5.23-debian5.0-i686.deb
- Package `mysql-5.5.23-debian5.0-i686.deb' is not installed and no info is available.*

Comment: No, without the extension. `dpkg-query --status mysql-5.5.23`. (Also try `mysql-5.5.23-debian5.0` just in case - package naming with dpkg can be a black art)

Comment: Sorry, dpkg-query --status mysql-5.5.23-debian5.0-i686
Package `mysql-5.5.23-debian5.0-i686' is not installed and no info is available.

Comment: No. Read my comment above! Don't put the i686. `dpkg-query --status mysql-5.5.23`

Comment: sorry, the same, dpkg-query --status mysql-5.5.23
Package `mysql-5.5.23' is not installed and no info is available.